# Can Android Studio display methods parameters in call?

Tags: android-studio, uiappearance, codehighlighter

Android Studio seems to be able to show the parameter name in a methods call if it is a direct string, but not when a variable is passed. Is there a way to always enable this for all parameters?

```
String string = "Stringvalue";
    myFunc("Stringvalue"); // Parameter is shown as myFunc(parameterName: "Stringvalue"); (see screenshot)

    myFunc(string); // Parameter is not shown
```

[image: Code example]

Edit: After @MarioBerrios linked me the options emtied the blacklist and turned off all hiding options in File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Appearance:

[image: Preferences menu]

Still the same - myFunc(variable) doesn't show the parameter while myFunc("exampleString") does.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the hints in File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Appearance and hit the "Configure" button beside "Show parameters name hints" checkbox.

You can also use the command "Parameter info" (Ctrl + P) to show it

Comment: Thanks! I didn't find the options in the menu. Still - while some other methods display some of their parameters - my example function didn't change what it displays. It still hides the parameters hint when I pass a variable.

Comment: It seems that only literal arguments can show hints as Yaroslav Lepenkin commented [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205418590-How-to-enable-parameter-hints-for-all-parameters-non-null-values)  Another link that could be usefull is [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-164312) one